# Apache beam pipeline cannot be updated on Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running a beam pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow. however, the pipeline cannot be updated with exactly the same code. The pipeline looks like [pipeline overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPabp.png). And the code is as follows

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.GenerateSequence;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.View;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionView;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PipelineTest {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PipelineTest.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] shit = new int[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < shit.length; i++) {
      shit[i] = i * i;
    }

    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<Iterable<Integer>> sideInput =
        pipeline.apply("Create", Create.<Iterable<Integer>>of(Ints.asList(shit)));

    PCollectionView<Iterable<Integer>> view =
        sideInput.apply("CreateSideInput", View.asSingleton());

    PCollection<String> done =
        pipeline
            .apply(
                "FakeData",
                GenerateSequence.from(0).to(50_000).withRate(10, Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
            .apply(
                "Map1",
                ParDo.of(
                        new DoFn<Long, String>() {

                          @ProcessElement
                          public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
                            Long element = ctx.element();

                            Iterable<Integer> v = ctx.sideInput(view);

                            String out = "element " + element + ", value " + Iterables.size(v);

                            logger.info("MAP1: " + out);

                            ctx.output(out);
                          }
                        })
                    .withSideInputs(view))
            .apply(
                "Map2",
                ParDo.of(
                        new DoFn<String, String>() {

                          @ProcessElement
                          public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
                            String element = ctx.element();

                            Iterable<Integer> v = ctx.sideInput(view);

                            String out = "element " + element + ", value " + Iterables.size(v);

                            logger.info("MAP2: " + out);

                            ctx.output(out);
                          }
                        })
                    .withSideInputs(view));
  }
}
```

I tried to provide default value for the view as well as use two views. However, neither of them work. If the view is used in two independent transforms, the pipeline can be updated.

Comment: Do you mean that the pipeline cannot be updated by redeploying the pipeline with the `--update` command line parameter?

Comment: @andrew Yes. First the pipeline was deployed without --update. Later, the pipeline was deployed with the same job name and --update.

Comment: Usually, an error is logged when a Dataflow job is not able to be updated automatically. Can you post the stack trace for the error? Draining and re-deploying the pipeline is typically the only workaround for this.

Comment: @Andrew `The new job is not compatible with ***. The original job has not been aborted., (***): The stage FakeData/Read(UnboundedCountingSource)/Read(AutoValue_BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource_UnboundedToBoundedSourceAdapter)/Read(AutoValue_BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource_UnboundedToBoundedSourceAdapter)/Read(BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter)/DataflowRunner.StreamingUnboundedRead.ReadWithIds has changed in a way that is incompatible with update.` We have to keep some states. So the workaround is not suitable.

Comment: @Andrew It seems the problem is more generic. I tried adding two independent sideinputs to a simple Map transform. The pipeline cannot be updated, either.

Comment: @Andrew You may find the pipeline having a transform with two side inputs here https://gist.github.com/lidalei/493c72a795166a6ff7e08416f7f303e2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any other workaround for this. This may be a limitation of how Dataflow serializes and executes a pipeline. You may want to consider redesigning the pipeline such that it is stateless and idempotent.